# Deriving X atom from Y atom

Tags: atomic-physics

I want to know that, is there a possibility of deriving an atom of one element from another element? I knew it is done in the Sun, by the process of nuclear fission. If so, why didn't scientists tried to derive Au (Gold) from any metal element? And I want to know whether this research is going on or dropped?

Comment: The process occurring in sun is Fusion and scientists probably have better things to do than deriving gold through fission :P A quote from wiki "It transpired that, under true [nuclear transmutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_transmutation), it is far easier to turn gold into lead than the reverse reaction, which was the one the alchemists had ardently pursued. Nuclear experiments have successfully transmuted lead into gold, but the expense far exceeds any gain"

Comment: @Gowtham you should probably add that as an answer

Comment: "*I want to know that, is there a possibility of deriving an atom of one element from another element?*"- In fact, all the atoms came from other atoms (except hydrogen). Read about: Steady state theory, Big bang theory, Supernova, nuclear reactions in stars, etc. You will understand how atoms were cooked and how you are the dust of star pieces, etc.

Comment: My master's thesis involved turning tungsten into gold. Looking at neutron deficient decay chains with $^{180}W(^{14}N,?n)^ATl$, decaying by $\beta +$. Many $$ per atom (thank you, USDOE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process occurring in sun is [Fusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fusion) and scientists probably have better things to do than deriving gold through fission. It is economically nonviable.

A quote from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_transmutation)

> It transpired that, under true nuclear transmutation, it is far easier to turn gold into lead than the reverse reaction, which was the one the alchemists had ardently pursued. Nuclear experiments have successfully transmuted lead into gold, but the expense far exceeds any gain"